# Mismatch on T value obtained from t.test vs summary(lm(data)) on R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

I'm doing an exercise on R about the hypothesis testing and I have the following data:

```
| Well depth (mts) | Water temperature (°C) |
|------------------|------------------------|
| x                | y                      |
| 600              | 200                    |
| 650              | 230                    |
| 700              | 280                    |
| 800              | 300                    |
| 800              | 310                    |
| 1000             | 350                    |
| 1000             | 330                    |
| 1000             | 360                    |
| 1500             | 410                    |
```

The hypothesis are:

$H_{0}:$ The depth does not affect the water temperature

$H_{1}:$ The depth DOES affect the water temperature

To achieve that, I have the following code:

```
well_depth <- c(600, 650, 700, 800, 800, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1500)
water_temp <- c(200, 230, 280, 300, 310, 350, 330, 360, 410)
geoterm_sys <- data.frame(well_depth, water_temp)

#lm (y ~ x, data)
lm_sist_geotem <- lm(geoterm_sys$water_temp ~ geoterm_sys$well_depth, data=geoterm_sys)
# Print linear model
lm_sist_geotem
# Get statistical info about the model 
summary(lm_sist_geotem)
```

Which gives me the following information:

```
Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-43.78 -24.65  12.75  19.28  29.28 

Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)            113.37638   33.65544   3.369 0.011941 *  
geoterm_sys$well_depth   0.21734    0.03615   6.013 0.000535 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Residual standard error: 28.05 on 7 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8378,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8146 
F-statistic: 36.16 on 1 and 7 DF,  p-value: 0.0005353
```

So far, so good. I get a t value=6.013 that matches my manual calculations. After that I get the t values from table with this:

```
qt(.025, df=nrow(geoterm_sys)-1) #t=-2.306004
```

Having a two-tailed test, I reject the null hypothesis.

However, when I run this:

```
t.test(x=well_depth, y=water_temp, data=geoterm_sys)
```

I get the following values:

```
Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  well_depth and water_temp
t = 6.2412, df = 8.8993, p-value = 0.0001586
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 373.6589 799.6745
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 894.4444  307.7778
```

Which do not match at all the previous calculations that I made. Specifically the T or even the df.

Even if I run the command only for x, the results do not match:

```
t.test(x=well_depth, y=NULL, data=geoterm_sys)
```

Which gives me this:

```
One Sample t-test

data:  well_depth
t = 9.7801, df = 8, p-value = 1.002e-05
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
  683.5466 1105.3423
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 894.4444
```

Can anybody explain why? Am I doing something wrong on the t.test command? Should I worry about the numbers?

Thanks!

**Edit:** Added hypothesis.

Comment: Hi. Basically the deeper the well, the hotter the water is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tests are testing completely different (actually almost contrary) hypotheses:

- The linear model tests if x and y correlate. You can easily replicate that by running something like

  cor.test(~well_depth + water_temp)  # t = 6.0129, df = 7, p-value = 0.0005353
- The two-sample t-test checks the null hypothesis that x and y come from distributions with equal expectation.

Now, assume e.g. that the x values are very similar to y. The t-test will fail to reject the null that their means are identical, while the linear regression will reveal a super strong relationship:

```
set.seed(345)

x <- 1:30
y <- x + rnorm(30)

plot(y ~ x)
cor.test(~ y + x) # t = 42.54, df = 28, p-value < 2.2e-16
t.test(x, y) # t = 0.029289, df = 57.989, p-value = 0.9767
```

[image]

Comment: So what you're saying is that t.test test (sorry for the redundance) checks whether the distribution is t shaped whereas cor.test checks if there is correlaction between the two variables?

Comment: Second one is correct, first one not. The two sample t test checks the null that the two population means are identical.

Comment: I see. Somehow in my head --_don't ask me why_-- I understood it as: Calculate the t from the data and then comparate the calculated t against those from the tables at 95% confidence (if not provided) with n-1 degrees of freedom.

Comment: You can actually do this, but you would need to calculate the t statistic behind the standard correlation test!

Comment: Something like this, right? `set.seed(345) ;x <- 1:30 ;y <- x + rnorm(30) ; my_cor <- cor.test(~ y + x) ;print(my_cor$statistic);print(paste("calculated t=",qt(.025, df=length(x)-1)));#confidence interval -2.04523 < t < 2.04523 not true, then reject`